# AngularJS - What would this look like had it been created TDD style?

Tags: angularjs, tdd, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm in the process of transferring all of our code onto Karma and Jasmine and am having a hard time figuring out where I start.

What would this code *look like* had I started building it from a TDD standpoint? What does a simple test look like?

*Note: This code works 100%, but I don't have any tests setup.*

```
(function() {

    "use strict";

    angular.module('system_centers', [
        'system'
    ])

        .factory('System', ['Api', function(Api) {
            this.loadSystem = function(contactId, cardId) {
                return Api.get('lmc/contact/system/' + contactId, {
                    card_id: cardId
                });
            };

            this.completeSystem = function(recordId) {
                return Api.put('system/complete/' + recordId);
            };

            this.createSystem = function(contactId, cardId) {
                if (+contactId === 0 || +cardId === 0) {
                    return false;
                }

                return Api.post('contact/system/' + contactId, {
                    card_id: cardId,
                    type: 'systems',
                    origin: 'lmc'
                });
            };

            return this;
        }])

        .controller('System_centersCtrl', ['$scope', 'System', function($scope, System) {
            $scope.main.cardType = 'systems';
            $scope.main.type = 'system_centers';

            $scope.completeSystem = function(recordId) {
                System.completeSystem(recordId).success(function(){
                    toastr.success("System completed!");
                    $scope.createSystem();
                    $scope.loadSystems();
                });
            };

            $scope.createSystem = function() {
                System.createSystem($scope.main.contactId, $scope.main.cardId).success(function() {
                    $scope.loadSystem($scope.main.contactId, $scope.main.cardId);
                    $scope.loadContacts();
                });
            };

            $scope.loadSystem = function() {
                System.loadSystem($scope.main.contactId, $scope.main.cardId).success(function(data) {
                    if (data.error) {
                        $scope.createSystem();
                    } else {
                        $scope.main.record = data.record;
                    }
                });
            };

            $scope.loadSystems();
        }]);

})();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Testing is easy, you just need to assert that your factory is working correctly. This doesn't mean that you want actually get/put/post stuff, that belongs to the `Api` test. Here we just want to know that calling certain functions of our factory will call some `Api` functions with the correct parameters.

I imagine that `Api` belongs to the `system` module. I load it and mock it:

```
beforeEach(module('system', function($provide) {
  api = {
    get: function(url, params) {},
    put: function(url, params) {},
    post: function(url, params) {}
  };

  spyOn(api, 'get');
  spyOn(api, 'put');
  spyOn(api, 'post');

  $provide.value('Api', api);
}));
```

`module` will load your `system` module and then we just need to create a simple object with the interface of our `Api` service. No need to implement anything on them.

Then we just need to spy the methods (to be able to assert that they have been called).

Next, we load the `system_centers` module and we inject our services:

```
beforeEach(module('system_centers'));

beforeEach(inject(function(System) {
  system = System;
}));
```

`inject` is used to inject dependencies in our tests. We just need to inject our `System` factory.

What rest are the test, I created a bunch of them:

```
it('should load the system', function() {
  system.loadSystem(1, 0);
  expect(api.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('lmc/contact/system/1', {card_id : 0});
});

it('should be able to complete the system', function() {
  system.completeSystem(20);
  expect(api.put).toHaveBeenCalledWith('system/complete/20');
});

it('should create the system', function() {
  system.createSystem(1, 3);
  expect(api.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith('contact/system/1', { card_id: 3, type: 'systems', origin: 'lmc'});
});

it('should not create the system if contact_id is 0', function() {
  system.createSystem(0, 20);
  expect(api.post).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});

it('should not create the system if card_id is 0', function() {
  system.createSystem(1, 0);
  expect(api.post).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

They are much the same. We call some factory method and we expect that our `Api` has been called with some parameters. Or even that calling `createSystem` with contact or card id with 0 won't call the `Api`.

Well, this is a good head start. You can continue with more tests or with other parts of your application.

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5vfg0Y1G0vo2nnz0xByN?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been searching for a good example like this.   :)

Comment: Great example, @Jesus; thanks. A question or two:
1) How do you choose between these two forms:
beforeEach(module('system', function($provide) {

Comment: [Ack! only 5 minutes to edit a comment?}
or the 
`beforeEach(inject(function(System) {
`  system = System;
form?